# Postgres custom json aggregate function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate

I have found myself writing a variation of this select a number of times:

```
select coalesce(json_agg(distinct id), '[]'::json) as id_list from table
```

and I would like to make a function that let's me write this instead:

```
select distinct_list(id) as id_list from table
```

just so I don't have to type the same thing a lot. I looked at the [user-defined aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html) docs and it looks like I'd have to define my own aggregation function that re-implements all of the functionality of coalesce/json_agg/distinct which I don't want to do. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway it's a pity that SQL does not support macros. But maybe your text tool does support regexp find/replace?

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. C'est la vie

Comment: Is the coalesce there only for the case where the table is empty, or does it have some other role?  You could declare your own aggregate reusing some of the functions which json_agg does, but since those deal with "internal" as a type, I think you would need to do that in C.

Comment: @jjanes I typically have a where clause on there which gives back empty results semi-frequently. This is just for convenience, really don't want to dive into C for something so small. I'll just deal with it